# cucumber runner not taking more than 5 files

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a folder with 50 files and my "features" in runner  is pointing to the folder correctly. when I execute the tests only 5 files are picked up and the test gets terminated. Btw, I named the feature files as MCTS-RCOLL-FS-CreateExpectation1,  MCTS-RCOLL-FS-CreateExpectation2 and so on upto 50. Please help me resolve the problem

Comment: Can you add the cucumberoptions you are using?

Comment: Show us how you run Cucumber.

Comment: import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
 
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json"}, 
     monochrome = true,
     strict = true,
     glue = { "classpath:com/orgname/projname/cucumber/stepdefinitions"},
  features ={"src/test/resources/EPOR/"})
 
 public class RunnerCuke {
 
}


I am running the RunnerCuke by right clicking on it and run as Junit Test